# How do I properly send data using a POST request to a PHP script?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**UPDATE:**
Tried debugging using an absolutely wrong method. I was double-clicking the .php file through Network tabs and assumed that it was sending the same headers as it would through the ajax POST request. That's why GET was working for me (because the data is packaged within the URL, double clicking the php file meant I was simulating exactly what would happen in the ajax request).

Thanks to @Phil for pointing me in the right direction: After using error to print back the resulting data, I found that the responseText included what I originally wanted from the POST request.

```
Below this point is the original post
```

I am trying to send 2 pieces of information through a POST request without using a form.

It seems to be sending the data properly as ''Form Data'' when I look at the headers for the php file in Chrome's Network tab. However, using `print_r($_POST)` to check if the data is being retrieved on the PHP side results in just an empty array : `"Array ( )"`

**JS**

```
url = "/members/duc.php";
data = {
            "d": "test",
            "r": 156
        };
$.ajax({
            'type': "POST",
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': url,
            'data': data,
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                jsonContainer = data;
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
```

**PHP**

```
print_r($_POST);
```

**Attempts at debugging**
5.  Changing ajax `method: 'POST'` to `method: 'GET'` showed the data on the server side with the code `print_r($_GET)`.
1. I have tried `$_REQUEST` and also setting an arbitrary `var = file_get_contents("php://input");`
2. I have tried sending as json then decoding input.
3. I have tried using `$.post` instead of `$.ajax`.
4. I have tried setting the data in ajax to `{duc:data}`
6. Tried the POST method with www. included in the address bar, no change.

$_GET was working because

---

---

Comment: Have you used your browser's network inspector to see what data is actually passed to the script? Is the "url" parameter actually resolving to the expected URL when the request is executed?

Comment: Yes, I'm double checking by opening the php file through Network Inspector to what is being printed out.

Comment: php does parse the json encoded bodies automatically. Your whole request should be in `php://input`

Comment: @zerkms `php://input` is completely empty. I tried with both the default contentType as well as the `application/json` type in the POST request.

Comment: maybe you edit different php file

Comment: @ewwink read existing comments and answers before commenting please, thank you.

Comment: it not answer, just to remind because many time i read people editing wrong file. and FYI your code is working properrly.

Comment: @AGN Maybe something about the transmission. Can you copy/paste the network headers as seen in Chrome's network tab?

Comment: @manassehkatz content length = 19 (with some added data) so it's sending fine with request method set to Post. Currently looking at other ways to retrieve the body content of requests.

Comment: How **exactly** are you determining that it is *not* working? You're telling jQuery to expect a JSON response but `printr` will not produce such a result and since you have no `error` callback, you won't see anything happen. What does the **response to the AJAX request** look like in your *Network* console? If it's something like `Array
(
    [d] => test
    [r] => 156
)` then your code is working *as expected*

Comment: @Phil By looking at what the php file is printing out through Network tab. It's only working with `Method: 'GET' and print_r $_GET` but not `Method:'POST' and print_r $_POST`.

Comment: @Phil The response text does have everything properly working however when the PHP is executing, it seems like the $_POST variable is empty. tested this by adding `error: function(data) {console.log(data);}`

Comment: Is php code `print_r($_POST);` only?

Comment: Any chance you could post some screenshots from the *Network* console? Specifically showing the request *Form Data* and *Response*

Comment: Can you explain your update? What was it you were doing wrong?

Comment: @Phil thanks man. Seems like I'm an idiot. I had double clicked the php in Network before and got the right json because it didn't require $_POST vars. After your post, I asked myself, "well... why is everything working in responseText but not when I double click the php?" So I looked at the PHP and there was data included (it was just linking me to the php file naked). I had originally debugged AJAX/PHP by double clicking the file but DataTables is all GET request I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

dataType:'json' is strict,check your php echo data type,make sure is json

try this

```
//js
url = "/members/duc.php";
data = {
            "d": "test",
            "r": 156
        };
$.ajax({
            'type': "POST",
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': url,
            'data': data,
            //'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                jsonContainer = data;
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
//php
print_r($_POST);
```

or

```
//js
url = "/members/duc.php";
data = {
            "d": "test",
            "r": 156
        };
$.ajax({
            'type': "POST",
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': url,
            'data': data,
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                jsonContainer = data;
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
//php
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

will get the data, but I think second is better.